# My brain doesn't work right now: What's the formula for the $n$th vertex of a discretized sine wave?

Tags: trigonometry, math-software, periodic-functions, elementary-functions

So far I have:

$$
A \sin(2\pi f ? + \phi)
$$

where $f$ is cycles per second, and $\phi$ is in seconds.  If I'd like to approximate the sine wave with $N$ points per cycle, and I want to draw $C$ cycles of it which could be fractional, how do I complete the above formula?  And by that I mean:

```
def placeSineWaveFunc(self, freq, amp, phase, cycles, pointsPerCycle):
    polyline = self.polyline
    numPoints = int(cycles * pointsPerCyle + 0.5)
    for k in range(0, numPoints):
         t = ????
         polyline.addPoint(QPointF(t, amp * math.sin(2*PI*freq*t + phase))
    # The rest of my placer method
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Michael not sure what you mean.  Please make an answer and see my above edit with code.  Sorry for my boneheadedness at the moment!

Comment: @Michael so you're saying $n = $ points per cycle.  Okay, then t = k / pointsPerCycle in my code above?

Comment: Well I suppose $x(t) = A\sin(2\pi ft + \phi)$ has period $1/f$, so you would actually want to use a discretization unit $\delta = 1/(fn)$. So plug $t \in \{0, 1/(fn), 2/(fn), 3/(fn), ...\}$.

Comment: I deleted my prev comments as I was implicitly assuming $f=1$.

Comment: @Michael I don't think $f$ should be in denominator like that, since it just automatically cancels each time.  See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it!  Thanks @Michael.

```
    def placeSineWaveFunc(self, freq, amp, phase, cycles, pointsPerCycle):
    polyline = self.polyline
    numPoints = int(cycles * pointsPerCycle + 0.5) + 1
    for n in range(0, numPoints):
        t = n / pointsPerCycle
        polyline.addPoint(QPointF(t, amp * math.sin(2*math.pi*freq*t + phase)))
```

\o/